# Transforming Huge Database table to Another Table

Tags: java, mysql, sql, performance, jdbc

We are migrating lot of data from our old database to new database.

Presently, both of them are actively[writing/reading] used based on flows/activity as migration is in progress.

Here's the real challenge for me now.
We have old database table which's still getting used now.

Atleast 100,000 new records are getting inserted every day and we need to move six months old data [01-01-2014] to new database.

We are using MySQL in both places. The new table to old table need some logical-transformation of data which will be carried through Java-JDBC, as the table structures and functionality is changed.

What are the ideal steps that I need to follow and taken care to do this transformation as quick as possible without fail.

As per my calculation, we will be migrating at least 20,000,000 records.

Some info:

1. Presently index exists only on ID column. creation_date exists
   without index
2. How to fetch efficiently these records, a better query
   to fetch??
3. Efficient way to transform using multi-threading
4. Efficient way to write the data into new database

Comment: If any one is -ve voting, please state the reason before doing that. It's perfectly valid question and asking for better approach and not code

Comment: Back ticks are for code highlighting. Your question contains no code so they're not appropriate. In any case, this is really a question for [dba.se]

Comment: Multithreading will not buy much for I/O bound processes

Comment: Can you post both table scheme, with index details and number of records it holds ..?

Comment: @Tarik, accepted. But A logical transformation time reducing is also as efficient as bringing down whole operation time right :)

Comment: @VinitPrajapati, can't post the schema. But tables hold more data and less columns (6).

Comment: I can't parse your numbers. What is `1,00,000` and what is `2,00,00,000`? @MikeW: And they will tell it's a programming problems a the OP is no DB admin. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure it answers your question, but in your case I would use an ETL (like Pentaho Data Integration or Talend). ETL = Extract Transform Load

Comment: @Reddy please be aware that the presentation of X,XX,XXX number format is highly usual around here. Using the westerners format of XXX,XXX increases readability.

Comment: @Tarik I would disagree that multithreadding doesn't help at all. I does help if you bottleneck is seeking time on the database as the DB can seek in more than one thread and thus is presenting the datasets parallelized instead of serially. Also it helps if you have errors in the transformation. Having 29/30 threads succeed means you now only have to redo 1/30th of the overall data the next time.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer Executing asynchronously would have the same effect as multiple threads. You made a good point though. Now, assuming data is sent in batches, the DB server might probably be overwhelmed executing I/O's, updating data structures and so on. As such, using a couple of threads might prove more than enough to keep the server fully busy.

Comment: @Reddy You might to set logging off at the risk of no guaranteed recovery in case of failure (no rollback of failed transactions). However,  it significantly accelerates row insertion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you to be able to alter both databases.
As you have written the data gets changed while the migration is processed, it shouldn't be so relevant how long it takes as the migration needs to be run more than once anyway. It has to cope with changing datasets, don't bother with performance, bother with correctness.

Start with adding an indexed boolean column to the old database to mark migrated data, so you don't need to migrate it more than once. If the data in the old database gets updated (and not only inserted) while the migration is in process use a timestamp column instead. Mark the moment in time where its been shifted last and the moment where its been edited last - that way you can see what needs to be transformed and what already has been.

Select data in chunks from older to newer. One chunk per thread (so first thread takes week 1, second takes week 2 etc.). If your table has no insertation date field use something else to split it - ID ranges, first letter of name, what have you. Make sure the sorting column has an index on it!

Then you process the data in this form:

1. Open transaction on both dbs.
2. SELECT chunk of data from old one
3. transform information
4. create [batch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29) for insertion on new side (row - per row)
5. create batch to mark for transformed on old side
6. execute both batches
7. commit both transactions only if both batches executed correctly.

Most likely the bottleneck here is the java <-> SQL Server network connection so using a sufficiently large connection pool is very important (at least amount of weeks since start +2 I would recommend).

After you have transformed all the data once you will need to re-run it quite often to keep the data up to date. What you do with collisions is up to you.

If you can do a cross-database selection from the old database an insertion trigger combined with a cross-database view will save you a lot of pain and soften the transformation.

Comment: Prepared statements and batch inserts will indeed accelerate the process.